# String or java.lang.String and Boolean or java.lang.Boolean in items.xml in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

When we define **java.lang.String** or **string** and  **boolean** or **java.lang.Boolean** as attribute type in items.xml in hybris.

Answer (score 1):

Since Hybris version 4, it is possible to use primitive Java types instead of the related wrapper classes e.g. `boolean` instead of `java.lang.Boolean`. The advantage of doing so is that the attribute definition gets a [default value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) automatically. This removes the need for handling `null` values.

Thus, you can change the following definition

```
<attribute qualifier="myAttribute" type="java.lang.Boolean">
    <modifiers read="true" write="true" initial="true" optional="false"/>
    <persistence type="property"/>
</attribute>
```

into

```
<attribute qualifier="myAttribute" type="boolean">
    <modifiers read="true" write="true" initial="true" optional="false"/>
    <persistence type="property"/>
</attribute>
```

and perform the system update to make the change effective.